# Amazon RDS index creation on large table over 300 M records

Tags: mysql, index, amazon-rds

I need to create a new index on large table in RDS MySQL. This index is needed to reduce the scan time on this table. Below is the configuration:

- Table size: 400 GB
- Records: 400 Million
- column - Timestamp-col
- RDS MySQL - db.m5.4xlarge, Engine - MySQL Community

Looking for below details:

1. How long such index creation takes place.
2. Will there be any outage to production DB. If so how to mange with lower impact.
3. Any good/bad experiences and lessons learned on such deployment.

Appreciate your inputs.

Comment: what does `select version();` show?

Comment: If you are worried about how this might impact your Production system, you could always create a Snapshot of the database and launch a new (non-production) database from that snapshot. Then, perform the change and see how long it takes and what impact it has.

Comment: For further discussion, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: @ ysth , select version is 5.6.50

Comment: @ John Rotenstein, Its good idea to first try on snapshot. I will check how this feasible at my work place. I will get back

Comment: @RickJames Table has 60 columns and some indexes (individual and composite). I am planning to add new index on close_date column . This column is part of already an existing composite key. But this is not helping on the query performance. When I created sepearate index in lower environment on closed_date (timestamp) it worked. Due to security reason not comfortable to share the table structure. If you need any specific. details then happy to share. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way we can predict how long it will take. This depends on the RDS instance size, the data types of columns you are indexing, as well as concurrent load on the RDS instance, etc.

MySQL 5.6 and later have Online DDL which is supposed to allow some concurrent query traffic against your table. Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-online-ddl-operations.html for details. There are some limitations to how "online" this is.

However, I can suggest a better solution: a free tool called [pt-online-schema-change](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-online-schema-change.html). This is what we use at my company, where we do hundreds of schema changes per week. It may take longer than creating the index directly, but it's not a problem because it allows you to read and write the table while it's running.

Comment: Thank you Bill for the response. I will go through the documentation of pt-online-schema-change. At my work place special review is needed before start using open source tools. Question, since your team is releasing many schema changes so I wanted to know how much time taken for a large table scenario in RDS MySQL. Any statistics would help to understand how its working practically.

Comment: We don't have much record of schema changes on large tables on RDS, because most of our MySQL instances are still on physical servers in our datacenter. We don't have many large tables on RDS yet. Also, our results would not be very useful to you, since your databases undoubtedly have very different load than ours. You're just going to have to measure your own schema changes on your own servers under your specific load.